# Custom ContactsDirectoryProvider is not called for some operations

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I've implemented custom ContactsDirectoryProvider which works fine when Contacts or Dialer applications are searching for contacts using URIs of the form ***content://com.android.contacts/data/phones/filter***

However when InCallUI or CallLog  are trying to retrieve contact info with 
URis  ***content:/contacts/phone_lookup***  the **query** method of my provider is not called.

Any advice please....

P.S.
I did not implement separate sync provider maybe this is the problem?

Comment: I've encountered this as well.  The phone_lookup URI works fine on Nexus 5x (emulator), Pixel 2XL, LG 6.  However, when I try it on a Samsung S6 or Note 8, the phone_lookup never gets invoked.  It works for filtering, but the query never gets called for phone_lookup (an incoming call or call history) as they do on the other devices.

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you find solution @themichaelscott ?

Comment: Nope @wast... i gave up and went with the toast callerId approach for samsung devices

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that we are using is to use a BroadcastReceiver to listen to incoming calls:

```
<receiver android:name=".domain.callerid.CallerIdBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then in the onReceive method of the BroadcastReceiver you can get the incoming number:

```
intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)
```

(This requires the READ_CALL_LOG permission starting with Android Pie)

Then you can use the incoming number to match a person and show a toast and or notification