# Samsung: Provider for ContactDirectory not supported

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, samsung-mobile

I did some tested related to the providers. My goal is to display a contact name stored in my app when you receive a call from this number that is not present on your phone. So the implementation is pretty easy, it works well on different brands (Huawei, etc.) but it's not working on Samsung.

In my AndroidManifest I have the required entries:

```
<provider
        android:name=".mypackage.MyProvider"
        android:authorities="xxx_myauthority"
        android:readPermission="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.content.ContactDirectory"
            android:value="true"/>
    </provider>
```

and in my provider the correct url matcher (I guess)

```
        uriMatcher.addURI("xxx_myauthority", "directories", DIRECTORIES)
        uriMatcher.addURI("xxx_myauthority", "phone_lookup/*", PHONE_LOOKUP)
```

Has anyone met the same issues with Samsung devices? Any idea what to do or where to ask for more details on Samsung side?

One of the things I noticed is what Samsung called "Customized Services". I don't know if my app needs to be part of some sort of program to use a custom contact provider...

All help is welcome.

Comment: We have a workaround that we are using: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54933545/1499750

Comment: @TheOnlyYam did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @TheOnlyYam I faced the same problem. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible with the Samsung Phone App as a Samsung mod said in [this](https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/applications-mobiles-services/request-contactdirectory-providers-in-samsung-phone-app/td-p/4742886) forum thread.